# Repaint trace in chrome bug

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a website with animations.
When the animation runs in chrome, chrome seems to fail in repainting the elements area, and leaves trace lines where the element used to be.
Does anybody know why this happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: How are you doing the animations?

Comment: Using jquery. The repaint "bug" also appears when I drag elements using jquery ui draggable, and also sometimes when I hide and show element.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the bug?

Comment: I've noticed this myself whilst animating text. It seems to have been fixed in recent versions on OSX though. At least for the specific cases where I noticed it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this issue myself, and with the help of google I was able to find a [forum thread](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/6533-how-to-fix-rendering-artifacts-in-chrome/) relating to this issue, along with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geekambassador/F2J3s/) reproducing it.  It looks like (according to the thread) this issue is fixed in version 23.  I'm on version 22.0.1229.94 m, and the issue occurs in my browser.  I'm not sure if there is anything you can do to eliminate this issue in earlier versions of chrome, I think you'll just have to wait until version 23 becomes the latest stable and everyone upgrades their browser versions

Comment: Well on ***Win7 - Chrome 23.0.1271.26 beta-m*** the issues is gone, if you view the page at 100% zoom. If you change that then the problems come back..

Comment: Well, the latest dev version is 24 afaik, so maybe it is fixed there.  If not then this is an issue for Google's bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Canary. https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs

If it is not occurring in here, just go with it; they will patch it soon. I have issues with css3 transitions (especially when animating things that start off screen, and it leaves residual tearing and it looks horrible.

If you are really desperate, try hiding and then showing the elements and it usually flicks them back into place, but this is not a brilliant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this bug is weird...
The most simple workaround which doesn't affect performance seems to be setting some style properties of the draggable/animated elements or container.

You should be able to fix it by setting border or outline property. 
For example:

```
 //body, .draggable
$(selector).css('outline', '1px solid transparent');
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BYsza/)